# How i can find the the largest power of two less than a number without loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm

How i can find the largest power of two less than a number without loop ?
Examples:

```
5 output = 4.
11 output = 8.
100 output = 64.
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the binary representation of numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by a range? If you mean the largest power of two less than a number, it is `2^floor(log2(number))`

Comment: @Beta - finding the highest set bit is hard without a loop...

Comment: @Floris: I think range is something like "less than X"

Comment: for example : 9 will be 8 ,5 is 4 and 20 is  16

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you want the largest power of two less than x, you get this from

```
Ans=pow(2,floor(log(x)/log(2)));
```

Comment: Why are you dividing by log(2)? Since log(2) is simply... 1?

Comment: @nirvanaswap I am using the natural log function  which is the one built in. `log_n(x) = log_e(x)/log_e(n)`

Comment: Nitpick for compiler's sake, needs an extra bracket: Ans=pow(2,floor(log(x)/log(2)));

Comment: @MASQ thanks and done!

Answer (score 12):

A bit fiddling way to do it with ints is:

```
// given an int number (which would be the upper value of the range)
number |= number >> 1;
number |= number >> 2;
number |= number >> 4;
number |= number >> 8;
number |= number >> 16;
return (number >> 1) + 1;
```

The idea is to turn something like 01010 to 01111, shift one time to get 00111 and then add one to get the result of 01000.

To see how this works consider that the input is either 0 or non-zero. If it's 0, then the result is 0+1 since all the shifting and oring just results in 0 (2 raised to the 0th power is 1, the lowest power of 2, and the answer for input 0).

For non-zero numbers, somewhere among the bits is the most significant set bit for that value. Our desired answer is that bit without all the lesser significant bits that trail it. So concentrate on that single bit, because that's all we really care about. When we do the bitwise OR with the first shift right by 1, we ensure that the most significant set bit is still set, and the bit one less than it is set as well, because 0100 | 0010 = 0110. Next we OR that with itself, but shifted by two this time. That ensures that we have the MSB plus 3 trailing bits. We keep doing that until we reach the limit of bits in an int. Here is the step by step of a full 32 bit value example:

```
01000000110100111000000011010011

01000000000100000000000010000010 |
00100000000010000000000001000001 = 01100000000110000000000011000011 (num |= num >> 1)

01100000000110000000000011000011 |
00011000000001100000000000110000 = 01111000000111100000000011110011 (num |= num >> 2)

01111000000111100000000011110011 |
00000111100000011110000000001111 = 01111111100111111110000011111111 (num |= num >> 4)

01111111100111111110000011111111 |
00000000011111111001111111100000 = 01111111111111111111111111111111 (num |= num >> 8)

01111111111111111111111111111111 |
00000000000000000111111111111111 = 01111111111111111111111111111111 (num |= num >> 16)
```

Now all that's left to do is shift that final value right by one bit, and then add one to turn all those 1's to 0's except for the most significant carry which sets the bit of our desired answer to 1.

Comment: This is an "unrolled loop"... I don't think that is what the OP wanted

Comment: Agreed, but I was assuming he meant without looping over the individual bits. If a person gets technical enough, should they consider whether the optimised pow(2 and log(2) output of the compiler has similar optmised unrolled bit fiddling loop?

Comment: But I admire the cleverness...

Comment: I think "no explicit loop" is all you can ask for. It does look a bit like a homework question...

Comment: how i can coding it in c++ :)

Comment: That **is** c (c++) ...???

Comment: Can you explain why those operations guarentees turning 01010 to 01111

Answer (score 1):

If n is the largest number of the range

```
return int(math.log(n, 2));
```

Comment: You need to take 2^your expression

Comment: Is this C# or C++?  I can't recall there being a `math` object in C++.  Did you mean `math::log`?

Answer (score 0):

You can either take the Log based 2 of the number, which will give you the power, or, if it is an integer, get the position of the highest bit set (but that would probably require a loop).

I haven't done C++ in a while, but in C# it would be:

```
        double val = 129;
        int power = (int)(Math.Log10(val) / Math.Log10(2));
```

using the rule that log<sub>n</sub>(X) = log<sub>y</sub>(X) / log<sub>y</sub>(n)

Answer (score 0):

```
// This only works if i >= 0, and it may overestimate by one power of 2
// if i is slightly less than a large power of 2. Fixing these issues is
// not difficult, so it's left as an exercise.
long largest_power_of_two(long i) {
  int exp;
  frexp(double(i), &exp);
  return long(ldexp(0.5, exp));
}
```

`frexp` and `ldexp` just fiddle with bits, so there's not even a hidden loop there (except possibly at the microarchitecture layer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a special CPU instruction, if available, e.g. the x86 `BSR`.

If you can bit-revert the number without a loop (perhaps, using a look-up table or another special CPU instruction), then you can revert the number, find the least significant bit set to 1, reset others and revert that back.

```
unsigned IsolateLeastSignificantOne(unsigned n)
{
  return n & -n;
}

n = BitRevert(IsolateLeastSignificantOne(BitRevert(n)));
```

For bit tricks and other useful things, refer to [this document](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/).