# C++ MPIR/MPFR interoperability

Tags: c++, mpfr, mpir

I'm working on a project that deals with very large integers, and have used the [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/) library, based on [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/) for the whole project so far.

I now require a logarithm function, which MPIR does not contain. Another library, [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/), also based on GMPlib, does have this.

Both have an integer class, and they are similarly named, MPIR has mpz_t, MPFR has mpfr_t. Looking at both, they appear to be based on the same base class in GMPlib.

Is it possible to somehow convert an integer in MPIR into an MPFR integer to use the log function? The inelegant way would of course be to use string as an intermediary, but this costs a good few seconds. Any help would be appreciated.

If context helps, I'm trying to implement this logic: [Highest power of 2 less than n](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14527528/2453421).

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaking, but I think you can get away with a simple trick: just make one call to `bitCount = mpz_sizeinbase(n, 2)`. This will give you the number of bits required to store your number, and the highest power of 2 less than n will be `bitCount - 1`.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right, but I'm not sure if I'm understanding your answer right. 81 in base 2 is 1010001, so bitCount would be 7. I'm not sure how (bitCount - 1) would help. Could you clarify?

Comment: Well, yes, and 2^(7-1)=64. Isn't this what you asked for? Highest power of 2 less than n?

Answer (score 1):

MPIR and MPFR can be installed at the same time. You could convert the MPIR object to a string and and then create an MPFR object using that string, but that's likely going to be much more inefficient than simply using mpfr_t types throughout your program.

If you'd like instructions on how to install both of them together, here are two videos than can help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S06mX5dwIJ0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=je5ei4rCFiw